# How to Extend the existing classes in Ext.js version 2.3.0

Tags: extjs, extjs2

There is no proper material for ext js 2.3.0 extending classes.
Please provide the required info or links for extending the extjs classes for version2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the documentation here http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/docs/

Then I would look at the Ext singleton object which expose both `extend` and `override` methods which should allow you to do what you're after.

This is an example of using the `extend` method from the demo found here http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/yui-ext/examples/grid/array-grid.html
The parent page of this is http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/yui-ext/examples/samples.html

Here in the below code, I extend `Ext.grid.GridPanel` to make `MyGridPanel` which then implements a new method called `yourMethod` which will then alert a message when the grid is clicked.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    // NOTE: This is an example showing simple state management. During development,
    // it is generally best to disable state management as dynamically-generated ids
    // can change across page loads, leading to unpredictable results.  The developer
    // should ensure that stable state ids are set for stateful components in real apps.
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());

    var myData = [
        ['3m Co', 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Alcoa Inc', 29.01, 0.42, 1.47, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Altria Group Inc', 83.81, 0.28, 0.34, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American Express Company', 52.55, 0.01, 0.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American International Group, Inc.', 64.13, 0.31, 0.49, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['AT&T Inc.', 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Boeing Co.', 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Caterpillar Inc.', 67.27, 0.92, 1.39, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Citigroup, Inc.', 49.37, 0.02, 0.04, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51, 1.28, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Exxon Mobil Corp', 68.1, -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Electric Company', 34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Motors Corporation', 30.27, 1.09, 3.74, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Hewlett-Packard Co.', 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Honeywell Intl Inc', 38.77, 0.05, 0.13, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Intel Corporation', 19.88, 0.31, 1.58, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['International Business Machines', 81.41, 0.44, 0.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Johnson & Johnson', 64.72, 0.06, 0.09, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co', 45.73, 0.07, 0.15, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['McDonald\'s Corporation', 36.76, 0.86, 2.40, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Merck & Co., Inc.', 40.96, 0.41, 1.01, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Microsoft Corporation', 25.84, 0.14, 0.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Pfizer Inc', 27.96, 0.4, 1.45, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Coca-Cola Company', 45.07, 0.26, 0.58, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Home Depot, Inc.', 34.64, 0.35, 1.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Procter & Gamble Company', 61.91, 0.01, 0.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['United Technologies Corporation', 63.26, 0.55, 0.88, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Verizon Communications', 35.57, 0.39, 1.11, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.', 45.45, 0.73, 1.63, '9/1 12:00am']
    ];

    // example of custom renderer function
    function change(val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
        } else if (val < 0) {
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    // example of custom renderer function
    function pctChange(val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
        } else if (val < 0) {
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    // create the data store
    var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: [{
            name: 'company'
        }, {
            name: 'price',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'change',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'pctChange',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'lastChange',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'
        }]
    });
    store.loadData(myData);

    MyGridPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
        constructor: function (config) {
            // Your preprocessing here
            MyGridPanel.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
            // Your postprocessing here
        },

        yourMethod: function () {
            alert('this is a new method'); // etc.
        }
    });
    // create the Grid
    var grid = new MyGridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            id: 'company',
            header: "Company",
            width: 160,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'company'
        }, {
            header: "Price",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: 'usMoney',
            dataIndex: 'price'
        }, {
            header: "Change",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: change,
            dataIndex: 'change'
        }, {
            header: "% Change",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange'
        }, {
            header: "Last Updated",
            width: 85,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'company',
        height: 350,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Array Grid'
    });

    grid.render('grid-example');
    grid.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e, this.yourMethod());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/84Lmu21L/

Comment: If i have created a grid panel using var MyGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({...}) and now i want to use to extend this MyGrid. i have tried Ext.extend(MyGrid, {....}) but it didnt work out.. can you please provide info how to use it with an example

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the use of the constructor containing MyGridPanel.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments); in any extend class

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question to be honest have a look at this, http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/01/06/inheritance-patterns-in-yui-3/ and this http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/base/